# Active hard drive protection system

Tags: hard-drive

As you probably know hard drives die from shock during operation.
I just wanted to ask if called. "Active HDD protection system" works on any disk or just for those with special controller?
For example, "Toshiba" provides the driver here:
[Toshiba HDD DRIVER](http://support.toshiba.com/support/viewContentDetail?contentId=4001739)

[Lenovo Active Harddisk Protection](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=izJTSYOgJzI)

Answer (score 2):

It only works with supported laptops i'm afraid.

Some laptops have an accelerometer/gyroscope that can detect when the device is falling. This triggers a retract of the HDD heads to a safe position in order to avoid damage. It's a good measure, but not failsafe, since the plates are still spinning.

If you want this kind of outcome in any other laptop, I recommend replacing your HDD with a SSD